# AWS SES Receive Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

In the new AWS SES Console, I don't have the option to Create Receive RuleSets.
All the documentation indicates it should be there in SES/Configuration.

Documentation states.

```
1.Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon SES console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/.

2.In the navigation pane, under Configuration, choose Email Receiving.

3.Under Receipt rule sets, choose Create rule set.
```

I have setup a MX record, but unsure if the option is plainly just not there, OR I have to setup something else first, OR the option has been moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Email receiving is only available in **eu-west-1**(Europe (Ireland)), **us-west-2**(US West (Oregon)) and **us-east-1**(US East (N. Virginia)).
According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html) link,

> Amazon SES doesn't support email receiving in the following Regions: US East (Ohio), US West (N. California) Asia Pacific (Mumbai), Asia Pacific (Osaka), Asia Pacific (Seoul), Asia Pacific (Singapore), Asia Pacific (Sydney), Asia Pacific (Tokyo), Canada (Central), Europe (Frankfurt), Europe (London), Europe (Paris), Europe (Stockholm), Middle East (Bahrain), South America (São Paulo), and AWS GovCloud (US).

So if your region is any of these not supported, maybe this is the cause.

Comment: Ah great thanks, I searched high and low for a reason!.

Comment: So if I am in Mumbai region, can I still use this feature by using eu-west region selected?